# TSQL :how to reset the value of identity column in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Is possible to reset the automatic value every time change  the value of another column ?

I have a classic database INVOICES  with two tables related (one-to -many), HEAD and LINES .

Table HEAD : ID_TESTA , CUSTOMER ... etc (the column ID_TESTA  is PK and also is identity)

table LINES : ID_TESTA , ID_RIGA , ITEM, PRICE , etc. ... ( columns ID_TESTA and ID_RIGA are togheter the composed PK , and the column ID_RIGA is also an identity.
This column ID_RIGA  should reset with each change of ID_TESTA value.

Example: now the table LINES it's  like this:

```
1 1 Article 100 €
1 2 piece  30 €
2 3 nails   40 euro
2 4 screws  50 €
2 5 wood    47 €
3 6 rows    38 €
3 7 crane   6 €
```

I wish it so :

```
1 1 Article 100 €
1 2 piece  30 €
2 1 nails   40 euro
2 2 screws  50 €
2 3 wood    47 €
3 1 rows    38 €
3 2 crane   6 €
```

In TSQL INSERT statements that feed the tables , I dont  write the identity columns , they are automatically assigned by the database.

Bye Bye 
Tank you

Comment: You have two identity columns in `Lines`?

Comment: No,only one (ID_RIGA)

Comment: I guess I'm confused then. Could you list the DDL and an example of the insert statement you've used?

Comment: I'm a little confused as well, but if you want to change the value in an existing identity column you can use `set idenity_insert tableName on`, then do your update, then `set idenity_insert tableName off`. Here's a [Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx)

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is wrong. You cannot achieve this with identity and editing PK is a bad idea anyway. Get rid of the compound key, let `ID_RIGA` be an identity and the PK of your `LINES` table. If you need a sequence number per `ID_TESTA` you should either have dedicated column for it and maintain it on insert/delete or dynamically generate it on select using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY <whatever> PARTITION BY ID_TESTA)`

Comment: Now I use "SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Lines OFF". If I set this option ON,after I have to enter a value for Identity....but which value?   Here the query:                                                    ` SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.HEAD OFF;INSERT INTO HEAD (CLIENTE,DATE,NUMERO)VALUES ('cliente','date',number);DECLARE @TESTA INT SET @TESTA = @@IDENTITY;SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.LINES OFF ;INSERT INTO LINES (ID_TESTA,ARTICOLO,PREZZO,QUANTITA) VALUES(@TESTA,'articolo',prezzo,quantita); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this when you query on the table:

```
select l.*, row_number() over (partition by id_testA order by id_riga) as seqnum
from lines l;
```

You can put this into a view so it is available wherever the table is used.